# Multipoint Server 2011 Local Password DART doesnt work

Tags: password-reset, windows-multipoint-server

We have a server running some thin clients which sits on a Windows Multipoint Server 2011 (basically 2008R2). Recently this server suddenly lost the trust relation ship with the domain and I can no longer gain access to it. It was built by a person a while ago who is no longer around and nobody knows the local credentials.

It is not a domain server, it is just s a Thin Client Server which is a Domain Computer in our AD structure.

So the first thing for me was to try the ERD recovery discs with Locksmith. I have created loads of different versions for Server 2008R2 for Multipoint Server for Windows 7 and none of them seem to work. I keep getting error messages for Locksmith and Computer Management Console. The Screenshot below is what i get

[image: Same Error message also appears when launching Computer Management]

I have also tried the Netdom command from the server but that also did not work. My only chance now is to reset the local password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd give the old tried-and-true [NT Offline Password and Registry Editor](http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/) a shot, personally.

Comment: thank you, I had my doubts if it will work on the newer OS's but it worked a treat